# C# Retrieving large datatable from mysql takes too long (200k - 20 column records)

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datatable, dataset

Im trying to get some data from datatable 
this is my code

```
          public DataTable getAllProducts()
    {
        MySqlConnection conSQL = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        conSQL.Open();
        MySqlCommand getProductsCMD = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT
                                                  products.*
                                                FROM products", conSQL);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(getProductsCMD);
        DataSet productDataSet = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(productDataSet, "Products");
        conSQL.Close();

        if (productDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return productDataSet.Tables[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Filling the datatable takes almost 10 seconds and takes at least 800mb of my memory. afterward i dump it to a class which is much lighter and my application will drop to 70mb. 
the problem is that 10 seconds (at least) . it takes too long. is there any way to make it faster?

Update:

to those who say call your data partially . i have tried that 
mysql bottlenecks the process. there is another list that we get from wholesale 200k . and it needs to be scanned and then check if we have that product in our database. 
200k times asking from mysql only for one datarow for the program to scan it and do its procedure took about 40 min 
but if i load all the datatable in program and filter it in my own program it takes about 5 minutes to finish the whole work. 
so mysql is a bottleneck in this case.

Comment: How many products are there? Memory use would indicate there are many so do you really need to load them all as opposed to loading on demand/in response to a search/in paginated form?

Comment: Loading in the universe from the database can be painful. Why are you surprised that 200K records takes up a lot of memory? To make it faster load fewer columns or fewer rows.

Comment: I dont have any issue with taking so much memory. its logic. but the problem is with the datatable being filled with data. that takes too long with mysql

Comment: One thing you could do to make it more efficient is open a data reader and loop through it to create your classes. That will at least avoid one step. However, it may be a better idea to only load what you need rather than the whole set of data if possible.

Comment: Good idea mike. the thing is i need all of them.

Comment: Can you show me how to use the reader to make the class faster?

Comment: When it is loaded into classes, are *all* the columns used? And are *all* the objects kept around? While there are probably better ways to filter/aggregate/page the data, the 800MB to 70MB is an odd observation as the memory is well in excess of doubled. Since the original query is as "select *", all columns will be loaded even if they are not used when converted into objects later. Likewise, if not all objects are kept around this represents wasteful data loading.

Comment: I need alteast 80% of the fields. i tried to only call them but no improvement.